# SwiftUI Use EnvironmentObject as a model for my ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mvvm, swiftui

I have an EnvironmentObject which stores user data. After making a call to `Firestore` I'm filling it with data and using it everywhere. The problem occurs in my view model. I can easily retrieve data from this model but for more complex things I need to use a view model.

***Can EnvironmentObject be used as a model for a view model or it should be used only for local preferences in the app, like storing some default values or preferences?***

*Is it better to use a separate model for my UserViewModel?*

While it is very easy to access its data, It is very hard to fill it with dynamic data after making an external call for example. Especially in the `SceneDelegate`, where it's almost impossible because I can not make a network call there.

`SceneDelegate`

```
let userData = UserData()

Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if user != nil {
        if let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "userDefaults") {
            userData.profile = Profile(userDefaults: userDefaults)
            userData.uid = userDefaults["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            userData.documentReference = Firestore.firestore().document(userDefaults["documentReference"] as! String)
            userData.loggedIn = true
        }
    }
}

window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: tabViewContainerView.environmentObject(userData))
```

`UserData`

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile = Profile.default
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil ? true : false
    @Published var uid: String = ""
    @Published var documentReference: DocumentReference = Firestore.firestore().document("")

    @Published var savedItems = [SavedItem]()

    init(document: DocumentSnapshot? = nil) {
        if let document = document {
            print("document")
        let messagesDataArray = document["saved"] as? [[String: Any]]
        let parsedMessaged = messagesDataArray?.compactMap {
            return SavedItem(dictionary: $0)
        }
        self.savedItems = parsedMessaged ?? [SavedItem]()
        }
    }

}
```

`UserViewModel`

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userData: UserData?

    init(userData: UserData? = nil) {
        self.userData = userData
    }
```